# Performance impact of adding columns to Magento 2 sales order grid

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, sales-order, performance

During extension development, we've used the following method to add columns to the sales order grid in Magento 2

1. Add custom table to installation
2. Add sales_order_grid.xml to add new columns config
3. Use plugin on the CollectionFactory -> aroundGetReport, inside which we use join on our custom table

   ```
   <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
   <plugin
           name="sales_order_shipperhq_columns"
           type="Company\Module\Plugin\Order\CollectionFactory"
           sortOrder="100"
           disabled="false"
   />
   ```

   ```
   $result = $proceed($requestName);
   if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
       if ($result instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection) {
           $select = $result->getSelect();
           $select->joinLeft(
               ['our_order_table' => $this->_resource->getTableName('custom_sales_order_grid')],
               'entity_id' . '=our_order_table.' . 'order_id' ,
               []
           );

       }
   }
   ```

We are seeing severe performance impacts on loading the sales order grid when these additional columns are in place on a "live store" with a modest number of orders.

I'm looking for some advice on how best to add these columns without impacting performance. We also want to avoid extending the core Magento tables: this would aid performance but [breaks compatibility with Enterprise split database architecture](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master.html).

Answer (score 0):

We found some performance improvements by

- Indexing against the order_id column in our custom table 'custom_sales_order_grid'
- Reducing the column size of the order_id field in our custom table

These changes improved performance.

We still see a slower load time with our custom table join than without, and we don't see any Magento specific changes available, as far as we can tell, to improve this.

Comment: Same issue here, adding an index in custom_table (or linked third party module table) on the column used for left join, is definityvely a real gain.

Answer (score 0):

Create Indices for all custom columns which are used in grid/filter rendering.

To Create Indices in SQL table example.

CREATE INDEX SALES_ORDER_GRID_DEVICE_USED ON sales_order_grid (device_used)

After Creating all Indices run full re-indexing and cache clean commands.
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean

Compare the results with old speed

We can use the below link also for setting the configuration for indexing
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales/order-grid-updates-schedule.html

It will improve the page load by 50%